# In React, how is it possible to make onSubmit take two actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am using [Uniforms](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms) to create a form submission for my project. I need the form to submit to my database while also clearing the form. I can make the onSubmit do one or the other but it appears that I cannot have both of these. What's the best route to get the program to register both? Here's my React const with the `onSubmit` action on the `<Autoform/>` tag:

```
const UniformsHello = () => {

  let formRef;

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Submit a track</h1>
      <AutoForm
        ref={ref => formRef = ref}
        schema={PostSchema}
        onSubmit={((doc => Submissions.insert(doc)) & (() => formRef.reset()))}
        placeholder={true}>

          <AutoField name="Song name" />
          <AutoField name="Album title" />
          <AutoField name="Soundcloud URL" />
          <LongTextField name="Story" />

          <div className="super-special-class">
              <SubmitField className="super-special-class-with-suffix" />
          </div>
      </AutoForm>
    </div>
  );

 }

export default UniformsHello;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may store the values from the form in an abject and then clear the from and finally submit the object, but in this case you won't be using the submit functionality and you have to implement a custom function that makes the submit.

Comment: I'm still rather new at React, could you update your answer with a code example? I think I sorta grasp the concept but seeing it in action would be so helpful! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    const UniformsHello = () => {

  let formRef;

  return(

    function handleSubmission(doc,formRef){
        Submissions.insert(doc);
    formRef.reset();
    }

    <div>
      <h1>Submit a track</h1>
      <AutoForm
        ref={ref => formRef = ref}
        schema={PostSchema}
        onSubmit={handleSubmission(doc,formRef)}
        placeholder={true}>

          <AutoField name="Song name" />
          <AutoField name="Album title" />
          <AutoField name="Soundcloud URL" />
          <LongTextField name="Story" />

          <div className="super-special-class">
              <SubmitField className="super-special-class-with-suffix" />
          </div>
      </AutoForm>
    </div>
  );

 }

export default UniformsHello;
```

Comment: ok had to alter yours a little bit but got it! so I don't get why, but I had to arrow function `doc =>` to the function in `onSubmit` (any way you could explain?) and then I had to move the function to above the return and below the `formRef` definition. I'll mark the answer as correct once the code is correct

Comment: normally you cant run two function calls inside a arrow function.so it would be better to have a separate function ,it you have more than one call to execute.

Comment: I guess I was just sorta confused on why that arrow function of `doc => handleSubmission(doc)` is needed instead of simply just putting what you had in the first place. So I guess the info is set in that doc variable and we are allowing it to be passed by the function?

Comment: arrow functions are just short hand for function(){}, in your case you trying to do two thing, submission and clearing the input, that is not possible.

Comment: thanks so the working code i have is using `onSubmit={doc => handleSubmission(doc)}` and moving that function `handleSubmission` above the `return` once that's fixed I will make your answer correct